# Did I identify these aircraft correctly?

Tags: plane-spotting, aircraft-identification

I photographed a couple of aircraft and tried to identify them, but I'm not sure if it's correct. For me, all of them look like an Airbus A320, but I'm really unsure. So which of these aircraft is an Airbus A320 and if not, what's the correct type?

Airbus A320?
[image]

Airbus A320?
[image]

Airbus A320?
[image]

Airbus A320?
[image]

Comment: In all three cases, the aircraft's registration number is clearly visible. Google that and it'll tell you *exactly* what type of plane it is (e.g., the second picture, OE-LEL is an Airbus 320-214 with CFMI CFM56-5B4/3 engines, configured with 180 economy class seats, which first flew on 6th January 2006).

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could clarify your question to say what you were unsure about. Are you interested in, say, identifying an A320 vs a B737, or A320 vs A319/321? The current question (Is each of these four photographs an A320?) really isn't much use to anybody but you; a question more along the lines of "How can you identify between A319, A320 and A321?" would allow an expanded version of @MikeFoxtrot's answer, which would be useful to *anyone* who had seen one of these types of planes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think that learning to identify planes _without_ searching the identification number is a good skill. So although this particular question may have been a little unclear, the actual category should not be discouraged, IMHO.

Comment: for this type of thing asking in chat would be better,

Comment: @flyingfisch I agree but that's where my second comment comes in. "Are these A320s?" is useful to nobody except the asker, because the answer to the literal question ("Yes, they're A320s") doesn't help anyone work out what's an A320 and what isn't.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like it :)

Double window exits over the wings, so no A321 or A319 (with a few exceptions such as Easyjet's A319)

Answer (score 4):

All correct.

When you look at the engines, you'll see that the British Airways A320 is equipped with different engines than the other three.

The Swiss and NIKI aircraft are A320-214 and use the CFM56 series engine build by CFM international.

The BA aircraft is an A320-232 and it has the IAE V2500 series engine build by International Aero Engines.